# How can I avoid .Average in a LINQ expression throwing an exception if there are no records?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Here is the LINQ query that I have:

```
 var t2 = t1.GroupBy(x => x.DateYYMMDD)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .Select(g => new ScreenTimeModel
            {
                 DateYYMMDD = $"20{g.Key.Substring(0, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(2, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(4, 2)}",
                 LearnTimeAvg = (int)g.Where(gx => gx.Mode == 2).Average(gi => gi.ScreenSeconds)
            }).ToList();
```

Problems happen where there are no records meeting `Mode == 2`.

Is there a way that I can default `LearntTimeAvg` to 0 in this case as presently it throws an exception and there's no list created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
g.Where(gx => gx.Mode == 2).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(gi => gi.ScreenSeconds)
```

It's usage is:

> Returns the elements of an IEnumerable, or a default valued singleton collection if the sequence is empty.